# can not pushViewController

Tags: iphone

I am following the tutorial at [HeadsUpUI](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HeadsUpUI/Introduction/Intro.html)

I just want to add extra function such as if I click on **play** or **pause** button from the **hover**, I will move to another view controller called **NextViewController**.

What I did is

> 1.- (IBAction)rightAction:(id)sender{
>
> 1. // user touched the right button in HoverView
> 2. [self showHoverView:NO];
> 3. NextViewController *controller  =   [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
> 4. [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
>       }

After clicking on either pause or play button, nothing happens at all. However, if i replace line 5 by

> [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

and it works.

Can somebody advice me if you know what the problem is. Any comments are welcomed here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no navigation controller, so you cannot ask it to push a new view controller. Any view controller can present a modal view controller, which is why your second example works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Make sure your class is a subclass of UIViewController. Your .h file should read :

```
.
.
.
@interface ClassName : UIViewController
.
.
.
```

Comment: even though you do have that but if there is no navigation controller, you can not still do pushViewController at all